# Locating element which has a hover state

Tags: java, css, html, selenium-webdriver

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dJvN.png)

I am trying to click on an image which has hover state. Inspect element highlights on class=wmagents_click_h and I have tried the following:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@class='wmagnets_click_h']/div"))).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@class='wmagnets_click_h']/div/div"))).click(); 

driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='c2canvasdiv']/div[6]/div"))

driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".wmagents_click>div"))

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@class='wmagnets_click']/div"))
```

I have tried this too:

```
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, e);
```

AND

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", e);
```

None of the above works. What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the html code for the div?

Comment: It's in the Code link (beginning of the post)

Comment: Add the error you are receiving if any.Make sure the selector finds a single element in the page or that the first element found is the want that you need.Also try with By.cssSelector(".wmagents_click div.wmagents")